# Get type of generic parameter from class which is inherited from generic interface

Tags: c#, generics, reflection

I have this interface and its implementation:

```
public interface IInterface<TParam>
{
    void Execute(TParam param);
}

public class Impl : IInterface<int>
{
    public void Execute(int param)
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

How to get TParam (**int here**) type using reflection from **typeof(Impl)**?

Comment: Remove the `;` from the end of your `Execute` implementation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use a bit of reflection:

```
// your type
var type = typeof(Impl);
// find specific interface on your type
var interfaceType = type.GetInterfaces()
    .Where(x=>x.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(IInterface<>))
    .First();
// get generic arguments of your interface
var genericArguments = interfaceType.GetGenericArguments();
// take the first argument
var firstGenericArgument = genericArguments.First();
// print the result (System.Int32) in your case
Console.WriteLine(firstGenericArgument);
```